# How can I be sure "apt-get install" successfully finished its work?

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I intend to download Skyrim. So I put the command into the terminal `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`.

Everything was loading fine and it seemed to be working, however before it finished it brought up:

```
Setting up libpam-winbind:amd64 (2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7) ...
Setting up odbcinst1debian2:amd64 (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5) ...
Setting up liblwp-protocol-https-perl (6.04-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libwww-perl (6.05-2) ...
Setting up icoutils (0.31.0-2) ...
Setting up unixodbc (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5) ...
Setting up gnome-exe-thumbnailer (0.9.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up odbcinst (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5) ...
Setting up wine1.6 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up wine1.6-i386 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up wine (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up playonlinux (4.2.2-1) ...
Setting up wine1.6-amd64 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.5)
Setting up libpam-winbind:amd64 (2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7) ...
Setting up odbcinst1debian2:amd64 (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5) ...
Setting up liblwp-protocol-https-perl (6.04-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libwww-perl (6.05-2) ...
Setting up icoutils (0.31.0-2) ...
Setting up unixodbc (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5) ...
Setting up gnome-exe-thumbnailer (0.9.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up odbcinst (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5) ...
Setting up wine1.6 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up wine1.6-i386 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up wine (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up playonlinux (4.2.2-1) ...
Setting up wine1.6-amd64 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.5) ...
moonshadows@moonshadows-A740GM-M:~$
```

It doesn't look like an error, however it does not look like it finished downloading. My question is, is there something more I need to type in to finish the process or is it done? I don't want to close out of the terminal until I am sure I am done so that I don't have to repeat everything.  Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: apt-get errors are usually clearly marked, beginning with something like  `E: error goes here`. Nothing of that sort has shown up in the output, so you should be fine :)

Comment: When it says `Setting up`, it is already done downloading and is only doing local configuration... Just as a side note.

Comment: You can always click on the `x` of your terminal window. If any command is still running in there in foreground, it won't exit but show you a prompt to confirm you want to abort the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problems here!

The **moonshadows@moonshadows-A740GM-M:~$** part is where you can enter your commands, so whenever it comes up, you know the previous process has finished.

So you can safely exit the terminal and playonlinux will work fine.

Comment: I thought so, I just had to be sure. Thank you so much. I can usually figure it out myself, however the forums have been very helpful.

Comment: @MoonShadows If my answer was useful, accept it so that the question is closed.